# Reputation score in top bar doesn't update after unupvote

Tags: support, live-refresh

Earlier today, someone upvoted one of my answers (on Stack Overflow) and the displayed reputation in the top bar increased by 10, like it [now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes) should. A short while later, the upvote was retracted, but the displayed reputation didn't decrease until the page was reloaded.

Is it a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), or is it [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design)?

As far as I'm concerned, it's [status-who-cares](/questions/tagged/status-who-cares), but I thought I'd let you know.

Comment: I had this happen before too. Not an overly common case, I'm sure, but it'd be nice for consistency's sake if vote retractions worked the same way.

Comment: It appears that the reputation score at the top of the page does not go down following an unupvote, an unaccept, or a downvote.  The actual reputation score as checked on one's profile page is correct (or even a page refresh wherever you are), but the display at the top of the page just doesn't update when the reputation score goes down.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design).

The job that deals with unupvotes doesn't seem to run very frequently, but the reputation will sync up eventually.

Comment: Nope. You're thinking of removed posts, unupvotes are instantaneous.

Comment: @lunboks - Not in my experience. If they are supposed to be then this is a [meta-tag:bug]

Comment: Well, you can just test it. Unupvote an old post that has been edited since. The user's rep will change instantly and the unupvote will show up in the rep history as well.

Comment: @lunboks But you can't see whether the display in the user's top bar changes instantaneously.

Comment: Oded, is your answer inferred from personal experience, or have you official information? Seems a bit odd that upvotes and unaccepts are displayed immediately, but not unupvotes.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Personal experience. Perhaps my [status-by-design] answer was out of place.