# Displayed Reputation too High (Transient Issue)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation score in top bar doesn’t update after unupvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130103/reputation-score-in-top-bar-doesnt-update-after-unupvote)

I have noticed a few times over the past week or so that my reputation as displayed at the top of the Questions page on Stack Overflow is too high, and refreshing the page lowers it by 10-15 points.  For example right now, a tab that was open last night shows a rep of 29,795.  However, a tab that I refreshed this morning shows 29,780.

If I click through to https://stackoverflow.com/users/141172/eric-j?tab=reputation I see the 29,780 value and *also see* that there have been no downward adjustments to my reputation today or yesterday (two days ago there was a -10 adjustment for a deleted user).

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: Have you ticked "Show removed posts" at the bottom of the reputation page? It seems a zero-votes accepted answer of yours was deleted (most likely along with the question).

Comment: I suspect it's the same issue as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130103/reputation-score-in-top-bar-doesnt-update-after-unupvote, unupvotes and unaccepts seem to not always get to the live-updated top bar. Refreshing syncs it.

Comment: @Matt: Didn't know that flag was there :-)  However, when I check it, I see -40 yesterday from a removed post.  The points still don't add up properly.  Also, with that flag checked, there are no reputation movements that aren't an even multiple of 10, so don't know how the difference of 15 could have been true at any point in time.

Comment: @DanielFischer: See previous comment.  I don't see how 29,795 could have been accurate at any point in time over the past 48 hours.

Comment: @EricJ. Possibly somebody accepted one of your answers, +15, and unaccepted shortly after. That doesn't show up in the reputation tab (if "shortly" was short enough), but if the top bar updated on the accept, but not the unaccept, you have the 15 too much.

Comment: I thought all changes in rep are now recorded and show up in my reputation log.  Is that not the case?  I have seen `unupvote` changes in the past.